# Can you call List(T) placed inside another method, how to initiate List(T)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I´m new to programming and so this may be an idiotic question but I'm wondering if you can place a `List<T>` inside a method and access it and edit it from outside that method?

How should I instantiate the `List<T>` class to be able to access and edit it from another class? Maybe I cant´t even instantiate the list in this way.

Here is my code containing the initiating of the list:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>
    { 
       new Customer
       {
           Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
           Telephone="02-333444"
       },
       new Customer
       {
            Name="B",
            Telephone="03-444555"
       },
       new Customer
       {
           Name="D",
           Telephone="03-444555"
       },
    };
}
```

If I want to access and add or remove items from the list from outside this method what should I do? I´ve tried several things and could really use some suggestions? For example; I want to use `newCustomer.Add(...);` somewhere else in the code.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

You can return the list that you have created from your method:

```
public List<Customer> MyMethod() 
{

    List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>
    { 
       new Customer
       {
       Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
       Telephone="02-333444"
       },

       new Customer
       {
       Name="B",
       Telephone="03-444555"
       },
       new Customer
       {      

       Name="D",
       Telephone="03-444555"
       },

    };

    return newCustomer;
}
```

Notice that I changed your return type from void to `List<Customer>` then at the end of the function returned your generated list (`return newCustomer`).

When you call your method from elsewhere you will be able to get the returned list like this :

```
List<Customer> customerList = MyMethod();
```

Or if outside of the class:

```
MyClass instanceOfClass = new MyClass();
List<Customer> customerList = instanceOfClass .MyMethod();
```

This is the fundamentals of programming, I think you should read up some of the core principles before delving too far in to development.

Answer (score 2):

@ThePower answer is the correct one.
Anyway you could use a different solution: define that variable inside your class, so making it accessible from every method inside that class:

```
public class Foo 
{
    private List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>();
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
        newCustomer.Add(...); 
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Foo 
{
    private List<Customer> newCustomer = null;
    public Foo()
    {
        newCustomer = new List<Customer>
        { 
                  new Customer
                  {
                        Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
                      Telephone="02-333444"
                  },
                  new Customer
                  {
                        Name="B",
                        Telephone="03-444555"
                  },
                  new Customer
                  {
                        Name="D",
                      Telephone="03-444555"
                  },
             };
    }
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
        newCustomer.Add(...); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good points, I suppose it all comes down to the scope and purpose of the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow some other code to access the reference to the `List<T>` object. Either you could expose it as a property inside your class, or return it from the method. Going by the latter option and using your example above, you would change your method to look something like:

```
public List<Customer> MyMethod()
{
    List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>
    { 
           new Customer
           {
           Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
           Telephone="02-333444"
           },

           new Customer
           {
           Name="B",
           Telephone="03-444555"
           },
           new Customer
           {
           Name="D",
           Telephone="03-444555"
           },
    };

    return newCustomer;
}
```

And then you can access it using:

```
// ... some other code ...

// SomeClass contains the MyMethod()
var someClass = new SomeClass();

List<Customer> customers = someClass.MyMethod();
customers.Add(new Customer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the List from the method:

```
public List<Customer> MyMethod() {
    List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>
    { 
        new Customer
        {
            Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
           Telephone="02-333444"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name="B",
            Telephone="03-444555"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name="D",
           Telephone="03-444555"
        },
    };
    return newCustomer;
}
```

Now from outside this method you can do the following to acces your list:

```
List<Customer> customers = MyMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! Will try them!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the list somewhere outside the method (typically in a field of your class)

```
class MyClass
{
    private List<Customer> _customers = CreateCustomerList();

    public List<Customer> CreateCustomerList()
    {

        List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>
        { 
           new Customer
           {
           Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
           Telephone="02-333444"
           },

           new Customer
           {
           Name="B",
           Telephone="03-444555"
           },
           new Customer
           {
           Name="D",
           Telephone="03-444555"
           },

        };
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        _customers.Add(customer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return the new customer list from the method:

```
public List<Customer> MyMethod()
{

    List<Customer> newCustomer = new List<Customer>

    { 
       new Customer
       {
           Name="A",                   //Name and Telephone are properties.
           Telephone="02-333444"
       },

       new Customer
       {
           Name="B",
           Telephone="03-444555"
       },
       new Customer
       {
           Name="D",
           Telephone="03-444555"
       }
    };

    return newCustomer;
}
```

And then call the method with:

```
List<Customer> myList = MyMethod();
```

You'll then have access to it in the parent object and be able to pass it as parameter into other methods.  The general topic of variables being available, created and destroyed in code is called 'scope' if you wish to Google more info on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, which is sort of the point of having encapsulation.

You can though:

1. Set a variable outside of the method from within the method.
2. Return the list.
3. Pass the list to another method that your method calls.
4. Have the list captured by a delegate.